# How can i catch the ActionEvents for every single button out of an ArrayList?

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener, actionevent

My Problem is that I don't know how I can catch the `ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` for every button out of this `ArrayList`.

Output is a chart for a class schedule

```
private static List<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<>();
public static String[] doctobuttontxt = new String[20];
public static void buttons(Panel cp){
    int ctr = 0; //counter
    int ycod = 48;
    int xcod = 88;
    for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
        xcod = 88;
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
            JButton button = new JButton();
            button.setBounds(xcod, ycod, 75, 25);
            button.setText(doctobuttontxt[ctr]);
            button.setMargin(new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2));
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    actionPerformed(e);
                }
            });
            buttons.add(button);
            cp.add(button);
            ctr++;
            xcod = xcod + 88;

        }
        ycod = ycod + 48;
    }
```

And I can't use a `JTable`.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?

Comment: Apart from the infinite recursion at `actionPerformed`, of course.

Comment: nothing the code works. I only don't know how i can read out the `actionPerformed`

Comment: when i press a button i get
`at Stundenplan$1.actionPerformed(Stundenplan.java:75)`